# Confused about warnings.warn only displaying a warning once

Tags: python, python-3.x, warnings

I am using python's `warnings` module for the first time to issue warnings to the user. In particular I am using the `warnings.warn` method. I am quite confused about how it works, since in certain cases it only shows the warning once, but not again when executing the same code later. I want it to always show when it is executed.

I was not able to reproduce this in a minimal example yet. But here are screenshots of my code. `warnings.warn` is executed inside a class method (see below).

[image]

Above and below, I print `'Here'` and `'Still here!'` to know when the interpreter ran over the warn command. In this Jupyter Notebook I execute now multiple times a command, which each time should display the warning. But it only displays it the first time it rans over the respective line, but not anymore afterwards.

[image]

Why so, and how can I change that?
Thanks for help!

Comment: Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots ([how to format code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)). [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the behavior of the default warning filter. Quoting [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#the-warnings-filter),

> `"default"`: print the first occurrence of matching warnings for each location (module + line number) where the warning is issued

If you want a different behavior, [configure a warning filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#overriding-the-default-filter) to do what you want. For example, if you want all warnings of all types to always be printed, run

```
warnings.simplefilter("always")
```